# Tabuada em JavaScript - uma maneira simples de escreve-la

Tags: javascript

Essa seria uma maneira simples de escrever uma função tabuada em javascript? Se sim, como coloca-la numa tag?

```js
const tabuada = (...args)=>{
    console.log(`Argumentos que foram passados: ${args}`)  
    for (let valor of args) {
        console.log(`${valor} * 2 = ${valor*2} `)
    } 
}
tabuada(1,2,3,4,5)
```

Comment: Não entendi a pergunta. Você quer saber como criar a sua própria tag *HTML*, exemplo: `<taboada do="3"></taboada>` ou você quer saber como colocar esses valores dentro de um `<div>` ou `<span>`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Este codigo possui o seguinte resultado, assumindo que voce queira criar uma tabuada para qualquer que seja a quantidade de numeros passsados.

```js
function tabuada(...args) {
  for (const number of args) {
    construirTabuada(number);
  }
}

function construirTabuada(numero) {
  let color_td; // apenas para estilizacao.

  document.write("<table border='1px' style='margin: 20px'>"); // comeca a criar uma tabela.

  color_td = "#ccc";
  document.write(`<thead>Tabuada do numero: ${numero}</thead>`); // cria um titulo para a tabela baseado no numero.   
  document.write("<td style='width:30px;background-color: " + color_td + "'>Multiplicando</td>");

  for (let i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
    document.write("<td style='width:30px;background-color: " + color_td + "'>" + i + "</td>");
  }

  document.write("<tr style='height:30px;'>");

  color_td = "#fff";
  document.write("<td style='width:30px;background-color: " + color_td + "'>Resultado</td>");

  for (let j = 1; j < 10; j++) {
    document.write("<td style='width:30px;background-color:" + color_td + "'>" + j * numero + "</td>");
  }

  document.write("</tr>");

  document.write("</table>"); // termina de montar a tabela.
}

tabuada(2, 4, 7); // chamada de teste.
```

Ira produzir a seguinte saida para a chamada `tabuada(2,4,7)`, temos a seguinte estrutura no **HTML**:

[image: tabuada]

A funcao `construirTabuada` fica responsavel por toda a logica matematica e por construir o elemento tabela no HTML. Espero ter ajudado, se for dessa maneira que voce queria.

Comment: Isso mesmo muito obrigado.